# How to use jquery to grab data-attribute in every button that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fairly new to jquery and I want to use it in my application.
I have a table that contains some data like this:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Ariel <button id="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>Edit</button></td>
  <td>ariel@abc.com</td>
  <td>27</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Noel <button id="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>Edit</button></td>
  <td>noel@abc.com</td>
  <td>31</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  ...
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to use jquery to grab data-id when `<button>` was clicked. This is my code :

```
$(function() {
  var btn = $("#edit"),
      id = btn.data("id");
  btn.on("click", function() {
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

Only first row that can be logged. I don't know the syntax. What should i do?

@UPDATED@

I found a solution to use class instead of id. It is not valid to have the same id in some element. So i use this:

```
<button class="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>">Edit</button>
```

And make some changes in my jquery:

```
$(".edit").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.data("id");
    $this.on("click", function() {
      console.log(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: First we should not define two elements with same id and and you can set button class as "edit" and then try `$('button.edit).on('click', funtion(){    var id = this.data('id'); alert(id);});`.

Comment: @Devansh, yes thats true, so i have updated my question to use class instead of id. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have same `id` multiple times in a single web page. Use `class` instead.

```js
$(function() {
  var btn = $(".edit");
  
  btn.on("click", function() {
    var data = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Ariel <button class="edit" data-id="id-1">Edit</button></td>
    <td>ariel@abc.com</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Noel <button class="edit" data-id="id-2">Edit</button></td>
    <td>noel@abc.com</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my post!

Answer (score 2):

First we should not define multiple HTML elements with same id. You can change id to class and then try this...

```js
$(function() {
  $("button.edit").on("click", function() {
   var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Ariel <button class="edit" data-id="id-1">Edit</button></td>
  <td>ariel@abc.com</td>
  <td>27</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Noel <button class="edit" data-id="id-2">Edit</button></td>
  <td>noel@abc.com</td>
  <td>31</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the "**id**", which is supposed to be **unique** twice in your code. **jQuery** matches the first, because it assumes ids to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

**You can only use an ID name once in any XHTML or HTML document**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Ariel <button class="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>">Edit</button></td>
        <td>ariel@abc.com</td>
        <td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Noel <button class="edit" data-id="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>">Edit</button></td>
        <td>noel@abc.com</td>
        <td>31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Then bind click even to class attribute **

*Use data function for getting value of data-id*

```
$(function() {
    $('.edit').click(function () {
       var id = $(this).data('id')
       console.log(id);
    });
});
```

*Or use attr function for getting value of data-id*

```
$(function() {
    $('.edit').click(function () {
       var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
       console.log(id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1) You can add click event using `$("button").on("click")`

2) get id using `$(this).data("id")` inside click event

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
   var id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Ariel <button class="edit" data-id="id-1">Edit</button></td>
  <td>ariel@abc.com</td>
  <td>27</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Noel <button class="edit" data-id="id-2">Edit</button></td>
  <td>noel@abc.com</td>
  <td>31</td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
```